# Angularjs: Filter multiple criteria in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I would like to filter the msgs data by not displaying some message of corresponding userid. In the example below it only shows the message from Paul (userid: 11) & Kate (userid:12).

What I would like to do is to filter more than just one `userid`. Something like :

```
{userid:["!10", "!11"]};
```

which should display only messages from `userid 12` (In this case).

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/464FVab41YoV2BGFkgWt?p=preview

```
$scope.msgs = [{name:"John", userid:10, text:"Hello"}, {name:"Paul", userid:11, text:"hi"}, {name:"Kate", userid:12, text:"Hey"}];
$scope.filter = {userid:"!10"};

<div ng-repeat="msg in msgs | filter:filter">
   {{msg.name}} ({{msg.userid}}) : {{msg.text}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are half way there. You just need to add a filter that takes out the undesired user ids.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
        
        $scope.msgs = [
            {"name":"John", "userid":"10", "text":"Hello"},
            {"name":"Paul", "userid":"11", "text":"Hi"},
            {"name":"Pete", "userid":"12", "text":"'Allo"},
        ];
                  
        $scope.idsToTakeout = ['11', '12'];
        $scope.filterOutUserIds = function(i) {
            return ($scope.idsToTakeout.indexOf(i.userid) === -1);
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="msg in msgs | filter:filterOutUserIds">
    id: {{ msg.userid }}, message: {{msg.text}}
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I also created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9oTuMWoo8ubozvt5xF54?p=preview).